# Python, tamaño de dos funciones diferentes

Tags: python, variables, numpy, matplotlib, dataset

Sigo en mi camino de aprendizaje que por momentos se vuelve algo difícil.
Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto del curso que estoy haciendo, en el tengo que hacer la comparativa de dos barrios diferentes de dos ciudades distintas. He elegido Manhattan. 
Este es el DF que estoy empleando:

```py
NY = pd.DataFrame(NY.Neighborhoods.str.split(',').tolist(), 
index = NY.Borough.astype('object')).stack()

NY = NY.reset_index([0, 'Borough'])

NY.columns = ['Borough', 'District']
print(NY.shape)
NY.head()
```

Este es el resultado:

> ```
>     Borough         District
> 0   Manhattan CB 1  Battery Park City
> 1   Manhattan CB 1  Financial District
> 2   Manhattan CB 1  Tribeca
> 3   Manhattan CB 2  Chinatown
> 4   Manhattan CB 2  Greenwich Village
>                                                                             .
> Shape (48,2)
> ```

Luego de esto, una vez que tengo todos los barrios de Manhattan que quiero analizar he puesto la siguiente iteración para poder obtener la latitud y longitud de cada barrio para luego poder ubicarlos en un mapara. Esta es la iteración:

```py
for i in np.arange(47,NY.shape[0]):
    address = NY['District'].values[i] + ', New York'
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    print(str(i)+'The geograpical coordinate of ' +address +' are {}, {}.'.format(latitude, longitude))
    lat.append(latitude)
    long.append(longitude)
```

Hasta aquí todo va bien, obtengo los valores y ahora quiero introducirlos en el NY para que cada uno de los barrios tenga su lat y long.

```py
NY['latitude'] = lat
NY['longitude'] = long
NY.head()
```

Aquí es donde da el error:

```
    ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Entiendo que el error se produce porque lat y long no coinciden en tamaño con el NY, he mirado que tamaño tienen ambas variables y es de 53 datos, mientas que el NY es de 48. Lo que no sé hacer es arreglarlo o entender porque las variables son más diferentes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que las listas `lat` y `long` no están vacias al principio del código mostrado.

Aparte de eso, el bucle `for i in np.arange(47, NY.shape[0]):` con `NY.shape == (48,2)` resulta en solo una ejecución: con `i == 47` y ya tiene que pararse al llegando a `NY.shape[0]` que es `48`.

Una propuesta sería hacerlo como:

```
lat = []
long = []
for i in range(len(NY)):
    address = ...
    ...
    lat.append(latitude)
    long.append(longitude)
NY['latitude'] = lat
NY['longitude'] = long
```

Comment: JohanC gracias por la respuesta, lo pruebo cuando llegue a casa y te digo que tal lo que propones. Saludos

Comment: Si esta respuesta soluciona el problema, no olvides marcarlo como respuesta aceptada.